# MIN() in an array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, min

So here is my array, what I want to do is unset the [detail][$x] keys leaving just the lowest total.  Can anyone assist?  Thank you in advance..

There is alot of Products to loop though, what I mean is that its not just one item in the array.

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Product Name 1
            [detail] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [total] => 10.14
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [total] => 12.18
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [total] => 9.90
                        )
```

Comment: What language are you using here?

Comment: This looks like PHP.. Regardless, iterate through your `detail` array and save the key with the lowest total. Then, overwrite your `detail` array with the minimum total.

Comment: So your suggestion would be to overwrite IF lower as I build the array to begin with? That seems sensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out the lowest total and overwrite the whole detail. Something like that:

```
$lowestValue = false;
foreach ($array[1]['detail'] as $detail) {
    if ($lowestValue === false || $lowestValue > $detail['total']) {
        $lowestValue = $detail['total'];
    }
}

$array[1]['detail'] = array(0 => array('total' => $lowestValue));
```

Comment: I added an if(isset($lowestValue)){ because I was getting some strange results, with that added it works fine now.  I am guessing it must be something to do with $lowestValue = false; not resetting.  Would that make sense?

Thank you both for your prompt consise help, it is GREATLY appreciated. - Stu